# Socket Server Programming

Tags: c, function, sockets, unix, networking

I tried to make a server program that send and receive messages from client. I want to put the read and write instructions into functions because I want to reuse the code (next I have to send e receive more messages). The server works correctly, but when I put the write instructions into writeSocket(), the program rise SIGPIPE and I don't know why. I had tried also with a readSocket() function (simply copy read instructions into function) but I had the same problem.
Can you help me please?

This is code of my server program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXSIZE 256
int isTerminated(char buffer[], int len);
void writeSocket(int sock, char buffer[]);

int main(){
    struct sockaddr_in Local;
    struct sockaddr_in Client;
    short int port=1745;

    char buffer[MAXSIZE];
    int sockfd, newsockfd, n, nread, nwrite, len;
    int turn_off=0;//Controllare le impostazioni del contatore

    sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd<0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Server: Socket creating failed!\n");
        return -1;
    }else
        printf("Server: Socket created!\n");
    memset(&Local, 0, sizeof(Local));
    Local.sin_family=AF_INET;
    Local.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    Local.sin_port=htons(port);
    
    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&Local, sizeof(Local))<0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Server: Binding socket failed!\n");
        return -1;
    }else
        printf("Server: Bind ok!\n");

    if(listen(sockfd, 10)<0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Server: Listen failed!\n");
        return -1;
    }else
        printf("Server: Listen ok!\n");

    while(1){
        buffer[0]='\0';
        printf("Server: Waiting for connection...\n");
        newsockfd=accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&Client, &len);
        printf("Server: Connection accepted!\n");


        nread=0;
        while((n=read(newsockfd, &(buffer[nread]), MAXSIZE))>0){
            nread+=n;
            printf("Server: Ho letto %d caratteri con %d totali!\n", n, nread);
            if(isTerminated(buffer, nread))//Fine stringa
                break;
        }
        buffer[nread]='\0';


        printf("Ho ricevuto il messaggio %s\n", buffer);
        if(!strcmp(buffer, "Turn OFF")){
            buffer[0]='\0';
            strcpy(buffer, "Counter OFF");
            turn_off=1;
        }else{
            buffer[0]='\0';
            strcpy(buffer, "OK");
        }

        /*nwrite=0;
        buffer[strlen(buffer)]='\0';
        int str_len=strlen(buffer)+1;
        while((str_len>nwrite) && (n=write(newsockfd, &(buffer[nwrite]), str_len-nwrite)>0))
            nwrite+=n;*/
        writeSocket(sockfd, buffer);

        close(newsockfd);
        if(turn_off)//Spegni il contatore e salva la sessione
            break;
    }
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}

void writeSocket(int sock, char buffer[]){
    buffer[strlen(buffer)]='\0';
    int str_len=strlen(buffer)+1;
    int nwrite=0;
    int n;
    printf("Devo inviare il messaggio: %s\n", buffer);
    printf("Valore n: %d\n", sock);
    while((str_len>nwrite) && (n=write(sock, &(buffer[nwrite]), str_len-nwrite)>0))
        nwrite+=n;
    
}

int isTerminated(char buffer[], int len){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=len; i++)
        if(buffer[i] == '\0')
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SIGPIPE` when writing means that the other end has closed the connection.

Comment: You can't use `sockfd` for communication; that's the listening socket. Use the client socket `newsockfd`.

Comment: If the other end of a socket closes the connection, then `read` will return `0`. You need to check for that.

Comment: `writeSocket` does _not_ handle a -1 return (indicating error) the way your socket read loop does. Also, you may need to enable socket reuse. Add this _before_ your `bind` call: `int enable = 1; int ret = setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(enable));`

Comment: @CraigEstey IMHO using SO_REUSEADDR is bad practice unless you really need it (multi-process server for example). You usually don't want to bind to an already used port. If it's already used there is a problem.

Comment: Yes of course! Sorry for my mistake! I was sleeping LOL. Thank you guys!

Comment: 'nread' is used uninitialised:(